# How to give access to many classes, all derived from a base class

Tags: c++, oop, class, inheritance, polymorphism

I've got a class Figure, and its derived classes, King, Queen, Rook, Bishop, Pawn, etc. Also, theres the class Field, which models the characteristics of a chess field.

Now, all of my derived classes, namely King, Queen, Rook, etc. need to access private information held in class Field. How can I make this happen rather than manually writing in class Field: `friend class King; friend class Queen;`... ?

Is there a way to provide access to all those classes at once to the class Field?

Comment: Why do they *need* to access the **private** data? That sounds horribly wrong from a design point of view.

Comment: I think that a field could hold a piece, but a piece should not access a field of the board.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to guess that your derived "Figure" classes (King, Queen, Rook, etc.) need access to the private Field data in order to move themselves?

Ideally, I think that the Figure class should expose some kind of public method that uses some kind of data structure to describe its movement characteristics, and allow the Field to consume that public method in order to manipulate its own internal private data.  Each derived class should provide their own implementation so that they can return the correct data structure that describes their movement.

Alternatively, if you must provide friend access, I think you could probably try using `friend class Figure`, then expose `protected` methods on the Figure class to be consumed by your derived classes that allow them to manipulate that data.

Answer (score 2):

Refactor the classes so that the *pieces* don't need access to the *board*.

Answer (score 2):

Consider why the `Figure` subclasses need to access the `Field` members. Maybe because you want to check whether a `Field` is occupied by another figure already when performing a move?

If so, consider moving this logic into a dedicated class, like `Move`. For instance, a `Move` could hold a "source" `Field`" and a "target" `Field`. You could then have soemthing like a `Game::apply( Move )` method which applies a `Move` to a `Game` (modifying the game state). In this case, only the `Move` class would/might need access to the `Field` members.

This is just an example; the general idea is to figure out why all those `Figure` subclasses need to access `Field` in the first place, and then factor that part out into a common class.